# Show A Specific Item From Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Basically I have two column divs sitting besides each other. One holds thumbnails of my portfolio pieces. I want to be able to click on a thumbnail then have specific content show up on the div besides it.

My theory is that the content can be stored in an array and each thumbnail can have an ID that will correspond to its content's position in the array. So the first thumbnail image's id will be 0 and so on.

But I keep going in circles and have gotten nowhere in coding it. Point me in the right direction with examples?

Here is what I have so far but it is not working at all. Even with alert boxes with the variables.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var arr = ["item zero", "item one", "item two", "item three"];

$("div").click(function(){
    var thing = $(this).attr("id");
    $(#description).document.write(arr[thing]);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="port" id="15">stuff and things  </div>
<div id="description"> </div>
<script> document.write("hey " + thing);  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that you've tried so far? Without seeing any code, we can't really help, because we have no idea where you might have gone wrong. Remember, we're here to help you solve problems you've attempted to solve yourself. If don't demonstrate the problem and attempted solution, then essentially we'd just be writing code for you for free.

Comment: Typo:  you're missing a `);` after the last `}`. Avoid using `.document.write` use other methods instead to acc HTML or content to element.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (without usign ID and stuff) would be to put imediately after the image a hidden element with the description of your image.
Than using jQuery take that `.next()` (to the clicked image) element's text
and populate a designated target element:

```js
$("#portfolio img").click(function(){
  $("#js_Description").html( $(this).next().html() );
});
```

```css
#portfolio,
#js_Description{
  display:inline-block;
  width:204px;
  height:204px;
  padding:15px;
  background:#ccc;
  vertical-align:top;
}
#portfolio div{
  display:none; /* hide descriptions! */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="portfolio">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/8f8">
    <div>LIGHTGREEN</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/fa0">
    <div>ORANGE! Yumm</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ff8">
    <div>LEMON</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/8ff">
    <div>That's it...</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="js_Description"></div>
```

Comment: If you don't like jquery, JavaScript '.nextElementSibling' should work for you.

Comment: @www139 yup but there's more you know... And also the question is tagged jQuery so...

Comment: I agree with your judgment. I just thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @www139 OK but than mention also `addEventListener` etc etc

Comment: True but everyone already knows that. News oblong in JavaScript is harder to find/be aware of. I like your answer. Just trying to help anyone else. Happy 4th.

Comment: @www139 there's nothing to celebrate the 4th of July in my country. And BTW it's the 5. right now 8)

Comment: That's neat, in what country do you live?

Comment: I love this example and idea but its not working for me- even in its own single document of copied and pasted code.

Comment: Pauline, as soon as you see a jQuery code , you always need to make sure it's wrapped into a document.ready function. Most answers take it for granted that one understands this basic principle. So did I. Another way without document.ready function is to put your jQuery code `<script>` before the closing `</body>` tag. Also don't forget to include the jQuery library. Any questions?

Comment: @PaulineGonzalez if you struggle see this example: http://jsbin.com/joraqo/2/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks a lot Roko- I was wondering and confused about the document.ready function. I'm going to keep trying to make it work. May be back though- as you can probably tell I'm very new to jQuery!

Comment: @PaulineGonzalez no problem, just take a look at the jsBin link in my previous comment. You can download that jsBin and play locally. Happy coding

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Its working great but it won't accept any styling or HTML when it transfer. I have two separate paragraphs, a line break, and a hyper link plus two buttons. They do not work inside JS_Description and only show as plain text in there. Any ideas?

Comment: @PaulineGonzalez Yes, I know why. That's cause I've used the `.text()` method. You should use `.html()` like: `$("#js_Description").html( $(this).next().html() );`. Was this answer helpful?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes it worked! I can't thank you enough!